# Can't import audio to spark ar

Tags: m4a, audacity, spark-ar-studio

I tried to download song from YouTube and put it in spark ar.
It says that it must be m4a file so I converted it in every site in Google and I still can't upload it. Even when I downloaded Audacity it is not worked for me.

Comment: Please consider providing the solutions you've tried so far :)

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, but when I converted from stereo to mono it finally worked

Answer (score 2):

Use these settings and you'll be able to import the m4a files into your project:

- Sampling rate: **44100 Hz**
- Audio channels: **mono**